# How can I create a numba callable that has adjustable parameters?

Tags: python, numba

I would like to create a numba-compiled python callable (a function that I can use in another Numba-compiled function) that has an internal array that I can adjust to influence the result of the function call. In pure python, this would correspond to a class with a `__call__` method:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr
    def __call__(self, idx):
        res = 0
        for i in idx:
            res += self.arr[i]
        return res

t = Test([0, 1, 2])
print(t([1, 2]))
t.arr = [1, 2, 3]
print(t([1, 2]))
```

which prints `3` and `5`, respectively, so the result was different after I modified the internal array `arr`.

A literal translation to Numba using `jitclass` and numpy arrays looks like this

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.jitclass([('arr', nb.double[:])])
class Test:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr.astype(np.double)
    def __call__(self, idx):
        res = 0
        for i in idx:
            res += self.arr[i]
        return res

t = Test(np.arange(3))
print(t(np.array([1, 2])))
t.arr = np.arange(3) + 1
print(t(np.array([1, 2])))
```

Unfortunately, this fails with `TypeError: 'Test' object is not callable`, since Numba does not seem to support `__call__`, yet.

I then tried to solve the problem using closures

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

arr = np.arange(5)

@nb.jit
def call(idx):
    res = 0
    for i in idx:
        res += arr[i]
    return res


print(call(np.array([1, 2])))
arr += 1
print(call(np.array([1, 2])))
```

but this prints `3` twice, since closures copy the data in `arr` into an internal representation, which I then cannot (easily?) change from the outside.
I even tried to trick Numba, by using `ctypes` pointers on Numpy arrays I combination with `numba.carray`, but Numba still seems to copy the data, so I cannot manipulate it.

I understand that Numba wants to control the memory and avoid access to memory regions that might not be used anymore. However, I have a specific use case where I would like to avoid passing around the extra array `arr` and rather adjust the internal copy somehow. Is there any way to achieve this?

EDIT:
I tried the suggestion by Daniel in the comments to use a method different than `__call__`, but this also does not work. Here is what I thought might work:

```py
@nb.jitclass([('arr', nb.double[:])])
class Test:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr

    def call(self, idx):
        return self.arr[idx]

a = Test(np.arange(5).astype(np.double))
print(a.call(3))
a.arr += 1
print(a.call(3))


@nb.njit
def rhs(idx):
    return a.call(idx)

rhs(3)
```

This prints `3` and `4`, so the array `arr` can indeed be manipulated. However, using the instance `a` in a compiled method fails with a `NotImplementedError`, so I suspect this use case is not (yet) supported by Numba.

Comment: Whats the problem in defining a method instead of `__call__`?

Comment: @Daniel I tried what you suggest, but the result cannot be (easily) used in another compiled function; see edit to my post.

Comment: At least in the case of a simple function, globals are not only copied to some internal representation, but they are hardcoded in the compiled  function (no chance to modify it without recompilation). https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/faq.html#numba-doesn-t-seem-to-care-when-i-modify-a-global-variable

Comment: I agree that the Numba documentation is quite clear about how globals are handled in simple functions. However, I thought there could be a way to access data using some pointer-like structure, which could then be changed outside the scope of the function. However, it seems as if I have to wait until Numba functions support jitclasses as arguments.

Comment: Is using a simple shared library (written eg. in C++) which exposes two functions (eg. set_global_varibale, get_global_varibale) an option? This can be wrapped to Numba and should solve the problem, but I doubt that this is really wanted...

Answer (score 0):

Divide the problem in two parts, a numba function and a pure python class:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.jit
def calc(arr, idx):
    res = 0
    for i in idx:
        res += arr[i]
    return res

class Test:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr.astype(np.double)

    def __call__(self, idx):
        return calc(self.arr, idx)

t = Test(np.arange(3))
print(t(np.array([1, 2])))
t.arr = np.arange(3) + 1
print(t(np.array([1, 2])))
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess my initial post was not clear enough. I need the resulting callable in another Numba functions, so it needs to be compiled. I'll update my original question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need @property before the methods of the class but this may not be the only issue

```
@nb.jitclass([('arr', nb.double[:])])
class Test:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr

    @property
    def call(self, idx):
        return self.arr[idx]

a = Test(np.arange(5).astype(np.double))
print(a.call(3))
a.arr += 1
print(a.call(3))


@nb.njit
def rhs(idx):
    return a.call(idx)

rhs(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This effect is the result of [nopython compilation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/glossary.html#term-nopython-mode). If your goal is to create such callable at any costs, **even possibly without taking benefits from jit-compilation** - [object compilation mode](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/glossary.html#term-object-mode) is a simple solution for your problem. This may be acheived in your closure example code simply by providing `forceobj=True` parameter to `@nb.jit` decorator.

This code prints `3` and `5` respectively:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

arr = np.arange(5)

@nb.jit(forceobj=True)
def call(idx):
    res = 0
    for i in idx:
        res += arr[i]
    return res


print(call(np.array([1, 2])))
arr += 1
print(call(np.array([1, 2])))
```